# How can I implement current control for proportional valves?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, pwm, control, solenoid-valve

I am currently working on operating a [proportional valve](https://www.bibus.ch/fileadmin/editors/countries/bagch/3_Fluidtechnik/camozzi/Downloads/englisch/Camozzi_Serie_AP_Datasheet_ENG.pdf) for airflow, but I am facing some challenges. Initially, I attempted to control it using a [DRV8871](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8871.pdf?ts=1701402421200&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FDRV8871) motor driver with PWM frequencies of 500 Hz, 1000 Hz, and 2000 Hz. However, I encountered issues such as the valve body heating up and a reduction in airflow rate, eventually reaching saturation.

Upon reviewing the datasheet for the proportional valve, I couldn't find any specific PWM frequency recommendations. The datasheet did mention that the valve can be operated using current control. In an attempt to address the heating issue, I implemented a circuit mentioned below with PWM input which has OP-AMP [LM358](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358-n.pdf?ts=1701403685292&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM358-N%252Fpart-details%252FLM358AM%252FNOPB), which reduced the heating to some extent. However, the airflow rate still decreases, as observed on a Fluke meter.

I would appreciate any assistance or insights you can provide to help me identify and rectify the issues in my setup.

[image: current control circuit using BJT]

[image: current control circuit using MOSFET]

Comment: Please can you edit your answer to include what voltage the PWM is, and which specific valve you're using as the datasheet has a few.

Answer (score 1):

The 16-mm valve recommended PWM frequency is 1000 Hz; the 22-mm valve is 500 Hz.

Your circuit has just a few issues: An LM358 performs poorly going in and out of saturation, and even with an "ideal" op amp, the circuit would limit the current on each pulse to a fixed value.

Instead of this approach, I would suggest that you should drive the MOSFET in circuit 2 directly with your processor output, and use the LM358 to amplify and filter the signal on your sense resistor back to your processor ADC to give you an average current.  Then you can adjust the PWM to keep the average current at your target value as the coil heats up slightly and the resistance changes.

I would also add a "catch" diode across the coil to prevent voltage spikes from damaging the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZg73N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think you've mispositioned one of the feedback resistors on that sense amplifier.

Comment: Changed from unity gain if this is what you mean.